# setfacl operation not permited if I set rwx

Tags: permissions, executable

I have a deploy pipeline which runs under the deployment user. Pipeline need to set up permissions for some directories for www-data group. So I wrote this command:

```
setfacl -R -dm g:www-data:rwx /var/www/portaldev-api.lurity.com/temp
```

This throws me an error:

> setfacl: /var/www/portaldev-api.lurity.com/temp/cache: Operation not
> permitted

If I remove the X from rwx it works. But to delete files I also need x. Can somebody explain me what is the problem with x?

Thanks.

Comment: Filesystem of the cache directory?

Comment: Yes temp/cache/... setfacl should set permissions for all new created files.

Comment: Which FILESYSTEM  is used in the cache directory (ext3, xfs, fat, ntfs, btrfs, ...)?

Comment: df -PTh . | awk '{print $2}' returns ext4 and stat -f -c %T . returns ext2/ext3

Comment: is it mounted with the option "noacl"  ? see `man 5 ext4`